# Magento and taxes via SOAP v1

Tags: api, magento, soap

Is there a way to retrieve the tax rules in magento via soap v1?
Right now i'm keeping a duplicate "hard copy" in my order management software for the logistics department, but i'd like to be able to get and set it via the soap api if possible...

Is this possible?

Currently I use

```
function getTaxIds()
        {
        $taxids['1'] = 'NL BTW 19%';
        $taxids['2'] = 'US BTW 8.375%';
        return $taxids;
        }
```

from which I copied the matching id's from the magento backend... but this feels hackish tome and forces manual updates.

Is there a way to retrieve it without going through the pain of extending the magento api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Magento doesn't provide an API for Tax.

You can look at:
[Creating a Custom API or Extending the Core API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)

or just make a simple script that resides on Magento server that will display the data you need as json/xml and make a call to that file.

Comment: if you will build a module for this, I would get involved, just open a project on github...

Comment: I might do in the future, first priority will be to get it all working so we can put our website live.
When I start I'll let you know.